# Batch file echo closes cmd window

Tags: batch-file

I made this code and when I execute it, the cmd window closes. Can anyone find out the part that's making it crash?

```
echo off
title Test
color 0a

echo |welcome to my first batch file|
echo |                              |
echo |        Test text             |
pause
```

This code made the cmd window close when I run the batch file, and I don't know what's happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look into line 5 - 7: You'll find the the char `|` is echoed without escaping. Normally the pipe (`|`) redirects output from one program into the input of another, and when the command processor sees the pipe in an `echo` it thinks it has to redirect the `echo`'s output into "Welcome", which it can't do. More info on output redirection [here on SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) or [here on Rob Vander Woude's scripting page](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php).

---

By the way, here's the correct code:

```
echo off
title Test
color 0a

echo ^|Welcome to my first batch file^|
echo ^|                              ^|
echo ^|        Test text             ^|
pause
```

Comment: thanks for the code, i'll look into the website you give me

Comment: @SteveFest You beat me to it. I was so close. Nice answer, though.

Comment: @DennysBlake Aw. Just my luck, but next time you're gonna beat me :)